# Penlight vs stdlib vs underscore

Tags: lua

I am looking at the three above libraries for functions related to list/set functions: intersection, union, map etc...

Does there exist any comparison of the three libraries?

Answer (score 0):

There is not.

But feel free to give it a try :)